# max(count) from inner query using row_number()

Tags: sql, hadoop, count, impala, row-number

I am trying to pick the `src_cd` which has the maximum count in my inner query:

```
select count(*), src_cd 
from innertable1 
group by src_cd
```

Result for the above query is:

| cnt | src_cd |
| --- | --- |
| 100 | CCC |
| 90 | BBB |
| 80 | AAA |

From the above result I want to do a

```
select * 
from table1 
where src_cd having max(cnt of src_cd from innertable1)
```

I also want to use `row_number()` to pick the 2nd max, 3rd max and so on

Comment: [Why should I "tag my RDBMS"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms) - please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: the rdbms/database/tool is impala. i think its enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `limit 1` with order by to pick largest.

```
select count(*), src_cd 
from innertable1 
group by src_cd
order by 1 desc
limit 1
```

Order by will order in descending order of count.
limit will  pick up first row.

You can also use subquery to calculate next max rows using `row_number()`.

```
select src_cd as second_max
from (
select src_cd, row_number() over( order by cnt desc) as rownum
from (
select count(*) cnt, src_cd 
from innertable1 
group by src_cd
)rs
) rs2
where rownum=2 -- second MAX
```

Comment: Thanks @Koushik Roy the query with row_number() helped.                                                      below is how i used                      
  `select * from table1 where src_cd = (select src_cd as second_max
from (
select src_cd, row_number() over( order by cnt desc) as rownum
from (
select count(*) cnt, src_cd 
from innertable1 
group by src_cd
)rs
) rs2
where rownum=2`)